# best practice build connection on node js using mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

### how to make a best practice for build connection on node js using mysql

i've problem with using mysql pooling on nodejs, can u show me how to using this mysql pool with best practice?

i confused with connection.release(), connection.end(), and connection.destroy()

> can u show me best practice using mysql pool?

please help, thanks

Comment: Read this document may help you https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#connection-options

Comment: when i using connection.destroy()? after connection release or what?

Comment: If you read properly given document then you can find it out when to use which method.

Comment: and what if i give connection limit : 5, and the connection is full. i mean connection pool has 5. if i give some request connection again what happen?

Comment: All your questions are included in documentation..